# How to stop radio button from getting checked if there is a validation

Tags: angular

I have a layout with three radio button like this:

```
<div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="ABC" (change)= "showSection($event, 'abc')" checked>&nbsp; <span> ABC </span>
        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio"  name="optradio"  value = "EFG" (change) = "showSection($event, 'EFG')">&nbsp;<span> EFG </span> 
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio ">
          <label>
            <input type="radio"   name="optradio" value = "HIJ"  (change) = "showSection($event, 'HIJ')">&nbsp;<span> HIJ </span> 
          </label>
        </div>
```

Now i have two arrays

```
let array_one = [];
let array_two = [];
```

I have a validation that if `array_two.length <=1`  I should not be able to switch between radio button's

I have used angular my problem is i am able to implement validation but the thing is radio button is getting checked and reaching to the selected one.

for example :

i am on 2nd radio button and now array_two.length <=1 is satisfied but now when clicking on 1st radio button 1st one is getting checked. i have to stop 1st one from getting checked

please can someone help

Comment: please post a stackblitz example, i don't fully understand your question.

Comment: @Robert : i have to stop my radio button to get selected if conditions / validation get satisfied

Comment: Have you tried to bind the disable propriety of radiobutton to a boolean variable that check the condition statement?

Comment: @Robert : I cant make it disable these all three buttons need to be in enabled mode only.

Comment: https://angular-ubw5kn.stackblitz.io

Comment: in the above example just like if you click on any radio button it will simply give you alert and it will not change to the selected radio button. similarly i have to show a pop up if array_two length is more den 1 and i have to stop radio button button from getting selected

Comment: I guess you could do something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1qxajq?file=src/app/app.component.ts But seems like bad UX, I as a user would get annoyed and wondering why I cannot change the radio button value ;) But if you have some popup like you say, then that would be ok :)

Comment: I tried this event.preventDefault() still it is moving to different radio button and pop up is something i am able to see.. not working

Comment: well it works in the stackblitz! did you change `change` to `click`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that is what you want:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aphp8r

I created a formgroup that check the value of his children:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
  gender: new FormControl(),
  age: new FormControl(),
  city: new FormControl()
});
```

when you click on a radiobutton, his value get pushed to the array and the condition

array_two.length <=1 become true:

```
this.Gender.valueChanges.subscribe(
      (x) => {
        this.array_one.push(x);
      }
    );

    this.Age.valueChanges.subscribe(
      (x) => {
        this.array_one.push(x);
      }
    );

    this.City.valueChanges.subscribe(
      (x) => {
        this.array_one.push(x);
      }
    );
```

when an action is triggered on a formgroup, the formgroup check the formcontrol children and look at their value, if the value is null, it's mean that it's not been checked so it disable the formcontrol. To get that i'm simply iterating over an object to get the key, the key is the formcontrol name and i use that to disable it, if it is null.

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(
      (x) => {
        if(this.array_one.length >= 1) {
         for(var k in x) {
           console.log(k, x[k]);

           if(x[k] == null) {
             this.form.get(k).disable();
           }

          } 
        }
      }
    );
```

If you have any question regards the code or other things, please tell me. I highly raccomend you to go with reactive form[0] in order to have the full control on the logic.

[0]https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: I dont need such a great example robert i only need one way to stop my radio to going to new state selected if my array length is more then 1

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, you need to disable all the radio buttons upon a condition. For that, you need to use the `disabled` property binding with the radio buttons as

```
[disabled]="array_two.length <=1"
```

Stackblitz at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-disable-radio-group-on-condition